# Double Parameter in shell scripting throwing error

Tags: bash, unix, ksh

I am trying to make my scripts more generic and hence trying to pass parameter.
I have config file which contains variables (which are used in the scripts) and in the scripts ,I am sourcing (source command) the file in another scripts (ksh).

Config file contains:

```
p2020_m23_ORACLE_USERNAME=sanjeeb
```

Parameter for the script is `p2020_m23`.

ksh script:

```
export SOURCE_CD=$1
export CONFIG_FILE=/user/spanda20/dbconfig.txt
source $CONFIG_FILE

USERNAME=${${SOURCE_CD}_ORACLE_USERNAME} << **This throws error** >>
USERNAME=$p2020_m23_ORACLE_USERNAME  <<< **This gives correct result** >>
```

manual test:

```
[spanda2 config]$ export SOURCE_CD=p2020_m23
[spanda2 config]$ export m23_ORACLE_USERNAME=sanjeeb
[spanda2 config]$ export USERNAME=${${SOURCE_CD}_ORACLE_USERNAME}
-bash: USERNAME=${${SOURCE_CD}_ORACLE_USERNAME}: bad substitution
```

Comment: See [Bash FAQ 006](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) (it talks about ksh too) for all about this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
USERNAME_REF="${SOURCE_CD}_ORACLE_USERNAME"
USERNAME="${!USERNAME_REF}"
```

Comment: [spanda20job]$ export SOURCE_CD=p2020_m23
[spanda20 job]$  export p2020_m23_ORACLE_USERNAME=sanjeeb
[spanda20 job]$ USERNAME_REF="${SOURCE_CD}_ORACLE_USERNAME"
[spanda20job]$  USERNAME="${!USERNAME_REF}"
[spanda20 job]$ echo $USERNAME
sanjeeb

Answer (score 0):

`${parameter}` -The  value of parameter is substituted 
so If you want to append the value of 2 variables and assign in other . You should have written in like this

```
  export SOURCE_CD=p2020_m23
  export m23_ORACLE_USERNAME=sanjeeb
  export USERNAME="${SOURCE_CD}_${ORACLE_USERNAME}"
```

Answer (score 0):

In ksh you can use variable indirection with `typeset -n` or `nameref`.

Simple example:

```
    $ typeset -n that
    $ this=word
    $ that=this
    $ echo $that
    word
    $ this=nothing
    $ echo $that
    nothing
```

The name reference now makes `$that` return the current value of `$this`.